# I saw a post online, which a girl had put after haircut. I want to know what language is the code written in?

Tags: javascript, c#, programming-languages

After getting a  haircut, a friend of mine posted online a picture of it with the following code.

```
var hair = new Hair(Hair.TYPE_SHORT);
```

I want to know which programming language is it written in, just out of curiosity.

Is it javascript? C#? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript. because of the "var"

edit:

sorry yeah could be either javascript or C#

but I think most likely is C# now that I think of it due to "type_short" variable

Comment: But var is in C# too

Comment: oh yeah...but very uncommon. so it could be both javascript or c#

Answer (score 0):

var is used in Javascript to create objects. Var is also used in C# while storing a reference to an object of an anonymous type, when the type name cannot be known in advance. so If you can post some more part of code that'd be great to help.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript conventional constructor names do start with capitals but properties I think not(?). It's just a convention though and not a must. Nonetheless I vote for JavaScript